# How can a user lose all of their reputation?

Tags: discussion

Today I accidentally came across a Stack Overflow profile [Farewell Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133061/farewell-stack-exchange). They have a lot of badges and 1.6 Million in people reached, so should have a lot of points.

How did they lose all of their reputation?

Comment: that user is also suspended, during suspensions you are locked at 1 reputation point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How did he loose all of his reputation

**FYI** he didn't loose his reputation, his account is temporarily suspended

That  account is temporarily suspended all reputation will back after **Sep 17 at 15:26**

due to suspensions his reputation is locked to 1 point

Answer (score -8):

As Paulie_D already commented, he gave away a lot of bounties. As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2133061/farewell-stack-exchange?tab=bounties&sort=offered

Comment: *he gave away a lot of bounties* Wrong his account is suspended

Comment: @NileshRathod its not exactly wrong, he gave away nearly 2000 rep in bounties and this was l likely the reason he was suspended

Comment: @WhatsThePoint 'gave away nearly 2000 rep in bounties' - you suspect the users' account was hacked?  It's not against the rules/policy to place bounties, so I assume there is some fraud mechanism, (other than the usual black-market in rep between sock puppets etc)?

Comment: @MartinJames it’s more the fact he changed his name to indicate that he was leaving and then started giving away bounties, which indicates he was trying to give it all away